# Redis::CannotConnectError when testing Sidekiq web UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I am trying to test that admins can view the Sidekiq web UI.

```rb
it 'allows admins to view page' do
  sign_in admin

  get sidekiq_web_url

  expect(response).to be_successful
end
```

That's all. But unless I have Redis running locally I get the following, obviously:

```
Failure/Error: get sidekiq_web_url

Redis::CannotConnectError:
       Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

This is the only test fails if Redis isn't running locally, I would hate to make that a necessary setup step (eg. "Make sure you start Redis before running the tests" in the README or something) just for this one test, and also getting it set up with CI service.

Is there any way to get around this error for the specific case I'm testing, or possibly another way to write the test that avoids it? When I google it, I can't seem to find anyone asking about just being able to view the Sidekiq web UI page in a test.

Comment: I'm confused; you want to test the sidekiq URL is working (which in turn requires/depends on Redis running) but you don't want to require redis to be running? Seems like a Catch-22

Comment: Also - isn't the Sidekiq web portal for internal purposes only? I dont see why even having a test for that is even necessary.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan I can kind of see your point. It is internal but this came up when we were adding authentication to the web UI, it was previously accessible to anyone, which was bad. So now we want to make sure only admins can access it. We have tests to make sure other users get redirected/errors when trying to view, and I suppose that's sufficient. I was just wondering if there was a way to get the above test to work.

Comment: if you want the test to remain and are OK with redis not being running the only solution I can think of is to wrap the `get` call in a `begin/rescue` so the `Redis::CannotConnectError` doesnt bomb out